# I've got a question mark to TextInputEditText. What does it mean?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Sorry for this newbie question. While coding I've got such a question mark in my Android Studio. I wonder what does it mean? What should I make to remove it? I was solving my previous problem with hints attribute and another bug occurred.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNc8v.png)

Comment: see this link https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout

Comment: Will appreciate any other answers to this question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55541787/8242091.
(Would have commented but don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand what's wrong with my code.